# Gatsby production build warning with websocket

Tags: websocket, gatsby

I'm implementing a websocket on my Gatsby site (I'm using Websocket-Node package, socket.io is not an option), it works but when I ran the `build` command I get the following warning

```
warn WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage fs.readdirSync
    at test-project/node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js:73:1
    at test-project/node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js:64:1
    at test-project/node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js:40:1
    at test-project/node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js:21:1
    at test-project/node_modules/bufferutil/index.js:4:44
    at test-project/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
    at test-project/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketFrame.js:17:18
    at test-project/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
    at test-project/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:20:22
    at test-project/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
    at test-project/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketRequest.js:21:27
    at test-project/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
    at test-project/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketServer.js:22:24
    at test-project/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
    at test-project/node_modules/websocket/lib/websocket.js:2:22
    at test-project/webpack/bootstrap:19:1

  71 | function readdirSync (dir) {
  72 |   try {
> 73 |     return fs.readdirSync(dir)
     | ^
  74 |   } catch (err) {
  75 |     return []
  76 |   }
```

and this one below

```
warn WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage http.request
    at test-project/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketClient.js:254:1
    at test-project/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:62:1
    at test-project/src/utils/hub.js:6:16
    at test-project/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
    at test-project/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
    at test-project/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
    at test-project/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
    at test-project/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
    at test-project/.cache/_this_is_virtual_fs_path_/$virtual/sync-requires.js:7:49
    at test-project/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
    at test-project/.cache/static-entry.js:11:22

  252 |     }
  253 |
> 254 |     var req = this._req = (this.secure ? https : http).request(requestOptions);
      | ^
  255 |     req.on('upgrade', function handleRequestUpgrade(response, socket, head) {
  256 |         self._req = null;
  257 |         req.removeListener('error', handleRequestError);
```

I've tried using the recommended solutions from gatsby, including using `@loadable/component` library or adding a dummy component config on `gatsby-config.js` file but the warning persists.